# PHP Curl, Api connection, 503 status code

Tags: php, http, curl, https

I'm trying to connect selly.gg API, but even can't do that. I recieve an 503 status code as result of my code. Please tell me what i do wrong.

My API key: 3pnAUztziYgZDaAbNjYSuWSeNhtCjcfET8XLFxe8FH2W2kaoBg

```
<?php

$URL='https://selly.gg/api/v2/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("mega4642179@gmail.com:3pnAUztziYgZDaAbNjYSuWSeNhtCjcfET8XLFxe8FH2W2kaoBg")]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $status_code;
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Part of documentation exactly about what i trying to do:
[image: Part of documentation exactly about what i trying to do (image)]

Comment: 503 means: `The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance, which will likely be alleviated after some delay.`. It usually indicates a server issue, and not a problem with your connection string.

Comment: Please do not use images for code. Copy/paste your (relevant) code directly into the body of your question.

Comment: @FrankerZ yeah, but don't think such a big platform can have connection problems during all day, that's why i'm sure there is any wrong exactly with my code, do you see any mistakes?

Comment: @PatrickQ sorry didn't know that

Comment: @Folsten Then please take this time to read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn about creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and review other [help topics about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: @patrickQ ok, i already edit my post, thanks for tips.

Comment: @Folsten - yes it can - can be million of reasons for 503. It can be down for a maintenance or just traffic is so high that some users are skipped from the server web request - of course in that case it indicates that server's hardware needs to be replaced with better equipment. Or simply server don't has bandwidth limitation implemented yet.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas mhm, just i have 503 all this day since the morning, so, if no one see any mistakes in my code will try connect some hours later then, thanks for the reply man.

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @PatrickQ wow, very strange, for me it still doesn't work =_=

Comment: Just a guess - can be related that high traffic comes from your IP or your subnet, i.e. server may limit bandwidth according to geolocation. Try to run same code from other computer / net or through some proxy

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas man you're exactly right, approx 4 hours ago i used VPN for test and all worked... looks like my own IP and IP of my hosting blocked by this service, damn, i lost really a lot of time on that. Thanks to all peoples who tried to help me out